# FileUpload control's ".HasFile" property returning False even after file is selected?

Tags: 2013, web-part, file-upload

I am creating a visual web-part for my SharePoint 2013 environment. I am using `asp:FileUpload` control(`fuBrowseXMLFile`) in this web-part for uploading files to a document library. I have a button `Save` to initiate the process of uploading the file.

After deploying the code, i try to run it in `Debug` mode. I found that after clicking the `Save` button, when the debugger hits the following line of code,

```
if (fuBrowseXMLFile.HasFile)
```

`fuBrowseXMLFile.HasFile` returns `FALSE`. Whereas the file is selected in the control.

While searching for a solution, I came across lot of articles. But, unfortunately most of them talk with reference to `UpdatePanel`. I am not using `UpdatePanel` here.

I understand that it has to do something with `Postback`. But, I am not sure what would exactly resolve my problem.

Comment: Check `EnableViewState="true"` is set for the fileupload control.

Comment: @Amal it didn't helped.

Comment: Add this `Page.Form.Attributes.Add("enctype", "multipart/form-data");` in `Page_Load` event.

Comment: I already have it. Got this suggestion while googling. But sadly it didn't worked.

Comment: Is your file upload control in Update panel?

Answer (score 1):

Inorder to retain the selection during `PostBack` you should enable the view state property as below

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="fuBrowseXMLFile" runat="server" EnableViewState="true"/>
```

**Rest Approach**

```
<input id="inputFile" type="file" >
<input id="uploadDocumentButton" type="Button" value="Upload Document">

$("#uploadDocumentButton").click(function () {
    if (document.getElementById("inputFile").files.length === 0) {
        alert("Select a file!");
        return;
    }
    var parts = document.getElementById("inputFile").value.split("\\");
    var filename = parts[parts.length - 1];
    var file = document.getElementById("inputFile").files[0];
    uploadFile("ListName", "1", filename, file);            
});

function uploadFile(listName, listId, fileName, file){
    uploadFileSP(listName, listId, fileName, file)
    .then(          
        function (files) {          
            alert("Uploaded successfully");         
        },          
        function (sender, args) {           
            alert(args.get_message());          
        }           
    );          
}

function getFileBuffer(file){
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e){
        deferred.resolve(e.target.result);
    }
    reader.onerror = function(e){
        deferred.reject(e.target.error);
    }
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    return deferred.promise();
}

function uploadFileSP(listName, id, fileName, file){
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    getFileBuffer(file).then(
        function(buffer){
            var bytes = new Uint8Array(buffer);
            var content = new SP.Base64EncodedByteArray();
            var binary = '';
            for(var b=0; b<bytes.length; b++){
                binary += String.fromCharCode(bytes[b]);                
            }
            var scriptbase = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl+ "/_layouts/15/";

            $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.RequestExecutor.js", function(){
                var createitem = new SP.RequestExecutor("https://SharePointURL/SiteCollectionUrl");
                createitem.executeAsync({
                    url: "/SiteCollectionUrl/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('"+listName+"')/items("+id+")/AttachmentFiles/add(FileName='" + file.name + "')",
                    method: "POST",
                    binaryStringRequestBody: true,
                    body: binary,
                    success: fsucc,
                    error: ferr,
                    state: "Update"
                });

                function fsucc(data) {
                    alert('success');
                }

                function ferr(data) {
                    alert('error\n\n' + data.statusText + "\n\n" + data.responseText);
                }
            }); 
        },
        function(err){
            deferred.reject(err);
        }
    );
    return deferred.promise();
}
```

[Source](http://techfindings-prem.blogspot.com/2014/07/uploadattach-files-to-sharepoint-2013.html)

Comment: Amal, you are providing an alternate solution here. Do you mean the server side code will not work in this scenario ? If Yes, what explanation do you have in support of that ?

Comment: I didn't said server side will not work. Since its 2013 I just provided the REST API method.

Comment: The reason i don't want to go for REST in this particular situation is that i have already achieved a lot of functionality using server side code.